# how can use margin in division class to so it does not affect the outer division class

Tags: html, css

```
<div  class="header">
    <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

when i apply `margin-top` on inner div  `class="menu"` it  affects the outer div means the outer div is shifted by  same margin which is applied to inner margin.

suggest me how to handle this problem . I want to have margin-top from outer header div `class="menu"`

Answer (score 0):

There is more way how to avoid collapsing borders, you can use `padding`, for example

```
.header {padding-top: 20px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fqk9w9u9/

Or `margin` on `.header` and overflow: hidden on parent.

```
.header {overflow: hidden;}
.menu {margin-top: 20px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fqk9w9u9/1/

Or combination of `.menu`'s margin and parent's padding.

```
.header {padding-top: 1px;}
.menu {margin-top: 19px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fqk9w9u9/3/

Answer (score -1):

When you have an element together another element, the margin-top property is inherited.... To avoid it, you can put padding-top on the father element

Html code:

```
<div class="father"><div class="child"></div></div>
```

Css code:

```
.father{ padding-top: 50px; }
```